# How to loop through array with foreach inside while loop with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Im am inside a while loop and need to grab some data in array produced by the loop. My array looks like this:

```
print_r($fields); //produces this

Array
(
    [0] => 5, - not set -
    [1] => 9, - not set -
    [2] => 10, - not set -
    [3] => 11, - not set -
    [4] => 14, - not set -
    [5] => 19, 12
    [6] => 20, mm_cb_on
    [7] => 21, - not set -
    [8] => 27, Noe
    [9] => 28, Pena
    [10] => 62, mm_cb_off
)
Array
(
    [0] => 5, Two Individuals
    [1] => 9, - not set -
    [2] => 10, - not set -
    [3] => 11, - not set -
    [4] => 14, - not set -
    [5] => 20, mm_cb_off
    [6] => 21, 1
    [7] => 27, SecPartF
    [8] => 28, SecPartL
    [9] => 30, testname3
    [10] => 31, last3
    [11] => 33, 
    [12] => 34, 
    [13] => 36, 
    [14] => 37, 
    [15] => 39, 
    [16] => 40, 
    [17] => 42, 
    [18] => 43, 
    [19] => 45, 
    [20] => 46, 
    [21] => 48, 
    [22] => 49, 
    [23] => 51, 
    [24] => 52, 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 5, - not set -
    [1] => 9, December
    [2] => 10, 4
    [3] => 11, 2014
    [4] => 12, 1915 Canterbury Street
    [5] => 13, Austin
    [6] => 14, Texas
    [7] => 15, 78702
    [8] => 19, 14
    [9] => 20, mm_cb_on
    [10] => 21, - not set -
    [11] => 62, mm_cb_off
)
```

Each key has a key and value itself like so:

```
foreach ($fields as $keys) {

    $key = explode(',', $keys);

}
```

I am trying to set values for each item in the array, but need to check if something exists first. For example:

```
if ($key[0] == 19) {

    $prov_id = $key[1];

} else {

    $prov_id = '';

}
```

The problem I am running into is that not every array from $key[0] has "19" ... How do I go about setting an empty value if it does not exist? Am I mising something?

Comment: Try cleaning up the underlying data/array structure?  Not sure I really follow what the obstacle is you face.  Seems maybe over complicated.  As Razor says, `isset` jumps to mind.

Comment: I have tried something like this `if (isset($key[0]) && $key[0] == 19)` but it does not produce the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to check if there's a value at that array index by using isset() and if not, set your default value.

Answer (score 0):

Still be nice to clean up the array, make the first tokenized value simply the key for the array and the value just the value, to not need to think about that explode.

Anyway, try this:

```
<?php
$uglyArray = ['1,', '2,notset','3,imaset'];

foreach ($uglyArray as $k => $v) {
      $parts = explode(',', $v);      
      var_dump($parts);
      if (empty($parts[1]) || $parts[1] == 'notset') {
        //not set
        $uglyArray[$k] = "{$parts[0]}, A new value";
      } else {
          //has value
          continue;
      }            
}

var_dump($uglyArray);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
}

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "notset"
}

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "imaset"
}


array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "1, A new value"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "2, A new value"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "3,imaset"
}
```

To clean things up consider:

```
    $uglyArray = ['2,', '4,notset','6,imaset'];
    $cleanArray = [];
    foreach ($uglyArray as $k => $v) {
          $parts = explode(',', $v);                  
          if (empty($parts[1]) || $parts[1] == 'notset') {
            //not set
            $cleanArray[$parts[0]] = "A new value";
          } else {
              //has value
              $cleanArray[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
              continue;
          }            
    }


 array(3) {
  [2]=>
  string(11) "A new value"
  [4]=>
  string(11) "A new value"
  [6]=>
  string(6) "imaset"
}
```

Comment: I got this working, thanks. But now how to loop / get / set array(2) key[0] if it equals 3 and check that it does exist?

Comment: If I understand you, and I am not sure I do, I'd get my arrays keyed of sane indexes.  Then reapply the code I provided or leverage all the lovely native PHP array functions at your disposal.